# Delete data using given data from a table

Tags: sql-delete

```html
<?php
require_once("connection to server.php");
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="niceforms-default.css"">


<table>
<?php
error_reporting (0);
mysql_select_db("leave_db");
$mysql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$_POST[nameEdit]'";
$result=mysql_query($mysql);


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<thead>
<tr>

<table width="100%" id="rounded-corner" summary="2007 Major IT Companies' Profit">
   <tbody>
     <td></td>
            <td width="40%"><?php echo $row['Fname'];?>  <?php echo $row['Lname'];?></td>
            <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['Sex'];?></td>
            <td width="20%"><?php echo $row['Nationality'];?></td>
            <td width="20%"><?php echo $row['Role'];?></td>
            <td width="10%"><a href="delete_user.php?id=".$row[0] class="ask"><img src="images/trash.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
mysql_close();

?>
  <?php
require_once "config.php";
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $del=mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE UserID ='$id'");
  if($del){
   echo "<p><span style='font-weight:bold; color:#0000FF; margin-left:150px;'>Successfully deleted</span></p>";   header("Location:delete_user.php");
   }
  else
   echo "<p><span style='font-weight:bold; color:#FF0000; margin-left:150px;'>An Error while deleting ".mysql_error()."</span></p>";
 }

?>  
</table>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

that is my code and i want to delete data from my database it runs very well but does not delete data because i want to pick values that have been retrieved from the data base

Like
Name Username 
Ian   i234

so if one choses to delete using i234 it does not delete

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the code for delete_user.php.

I would also have a guess to say the following line is wrong:-

```
<td width="10%"><a href="delete_user.php?id=".$row[0] class="ask"><img src="images/trash.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
```

You can't just stick php inside html and expect it to work.

You will need to change it to the following.

```
<td width="10%"><a href="delete_user.php?id=<?=$row[0];?>" class="ask"><img src="images/trash.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
```

Comment: Also I would have a serious look at the layout of the HTML currently you are loading content outside of the HMTL document.